# WPF. control for add/remove string to observablecollection<string> via databinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have an ObservableCollection that I would like to be able to add and remove strings to via the UI, preferable achieved with databinding. The collection is already exposed such that in can be used in an itemssource binding expression..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion on what? It sounds you already have what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `DataGrid` to get the add and remove functionality. However, the `DataGrid` requires a parameterless constructor for the underlying items in order to support the add operation.

You can use a wrapper for string

```
public class StringWrapper
{
    public StringWrapper() { }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<StringWrapper> MyStrings
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Then your `DataGrid` can use it as `ItemsSource`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyStrings}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to bind the "selecteditem" of your view control to a string object and a button with a Command to delete it.

In that command you just have to do the remove logic.

To add a new one you must use a textbox and bind its text to a new string object. Then do the same as the "delete" button but in the opposite way.

Other option would be to use a datagrid but it depends on your view requisites.